# how to custom navigation bar in ios 5 and ios 6?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uinavigationbar

As I saw when I searched here it was a lot of questions on the same topic, but I really dont know which codes to use and where to put them.

I simply want to change the navigation bar to a custom bar with my own background image.

I did see some codes, but I am really new so I dont know how to do this!

[Like this](http://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/a/atmarkatmark/20071203/20071203220244.png)

-Simon

Comment: Your screenshot shows a standard navigation bar. You customise a navigation bar using the appearance methods described in the documentation. Can you explain which part you're having trouble with?

Comment: But where do i put the code? And i dont know objectiv c that good, working on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appearance property

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:yourimage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Comment: i have searched all over,but its just a mashup of old codes and stuff like that. And I dont know where to put it!

Comment: if you want to add the navigation bar for all the classes try it in app delegate, or add it in that view controller where you want to add the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

```
    //first put this code in AppDelegate.m
    in this method:

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {


      //code: navigationbar set image and fontcolor:

            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_navigationimg_bg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:0.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                                    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor],
                                 UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                            UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleGothic" size:20.0f]
             }];



            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            return YES;
        }


//second: put this code in RootViewController.m
    in this method:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.navigationItem.title=@"your title";


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```